# Should I edit my initial question when the solution I found to it turns out to be only vaguely related to the inital question?

Tags: discussion

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074750/copying-a-mysql-table-from-a-remote-server-to-a-local-server)

At first I thought my issue was related to my use of MySqlDataAdapters and bulk inserting. When I solved the issue it turned out to be related to my use of `MySqlDbType.Geometry` as opposed to `MySqlDbType.Blob`.

In it's current state I imagine the solution I posted will never be found by people who actually need it in the future, because the problem turned out to be something I did not expect and is only vaguely related to the initial question. Is it considered wise/acceptable to edit this question as to increase the chances of it being useful to someone in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. **A million times yes!** You have a question without answers posted to it and posted your own answer. By all means do edit your question and the answer too so that people see a clear link between the problem posted in the question and the solution. The final answer should no longer refer to the initial question but only answer the new question.

Ideally, you should edit the question *before* posting an answer.

Note that the editing I'm saying you should do above may not be enough to avoid downvotes or votes-to-close. If the question suffers from other quality problems or is a duplicate, people will vote accordingly. The usual quality standards still apply.

**Why should you do this?** A great deal of self-answered questions and answer are downvote-worthy because the OP posted an answer that amounts to "the problem was somewhere else". When they do this, they are telling us that the question they asked did not, in fact, contain a problem, and the answer is (in most cases) worthless as it does not explain anything.

It is a bit more delicate if you already have answers from other users to your original question. (Which you don't but I'm going to cover this too.) If the original question is somehow salvageable, it should be salvaged so that the answerers have not been wasting their time. For instance, if it is a problem that someone *could* run into if they had a configuration slightly different from yours (for instance), don't change this question into a brand new one. Clean it up, and vote on the answers if you are able to. **Pulling the rug from under the feet of people who have already answered is not well seen in our community, and could lead to downvotes.** If there is nothing you can do to save the original question, then I guess it depends on how many answers you got, and their quality. In some cases there may be no option that won't lead to a negative reaction from the community.